# Images are too dark and saturated in Image Viewer

Tags: colors, shotwell, image-viewers

Colors are coming up too dark and saturated in Image Viewer and in Whatsdesk, but look good in Shotwell, in browsers and other applications.

Here is the same image shown in Image Viewer and Shotwell for comparison:

[image: image viewer vs shotwell comparison]

How to fix this?

What I have already tried:

- reinstalling ubuntu-desk
- reinstalling nvidia drivers
- updating Ubuntu

Comment: Looks like issue with either your display color profile or image viewer does not recognize the color space of the image (e.g. Adobe RGB). Does it happen with all images or just some?

Comment: @pLumo it happens with all images(i tried many jpg, png etc.) when opened in image viewer but not in shotwell.

Answer (score 4):

Execute the terminal command:

```
xprop -root -remove _ICC_PROFILE
```